# Single query to display attendance of a student using student_id

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

The relevant tables of the database are declared as follows:

```
students (student_id (PK), full_name, semester, ...)
subjects (subject_code (PK), subject_title, semester)
teacher_attendance (class_id (PK), subject_code(FK), teacher_id(FK), date)
student_attendance (class_id (FK), student_id (FK))
```

Sample data:

students:

```
student_id - mca1701
.
.
.
<a lot of irrelevant fields>
.
semester - 3
```

subjects :

```
subject_code  subject_title   semester
CS006            Subject6           2
CS007            Subject7           3
CS008            Subject8           3
CS009P          Subject9 Practical  3
CS009T          Subject9 Theory     3
```

student_attendance :

```
  class_no  student_id  

      1     mca1801
      1     mca1802
      1     mca1805
      2     *mca1701*
      2     mca1702
      3     *mca1701*
      2     mca1704
      3     mca1705
      4     mca1601
      4     mca1602
      6     mca1803
      6     mca1804
      7     *mca1701*
```

teacher_attendance :

```
class_no  subject_code      teacher_id        date
    1       CS001             mca01     2019-01-14
    2       CS009P            mca01     2019-01-09
    3       CS009P            mca01     2019-01-09
    4       CS013             mca01     2019-01-17
    5       CS002             mca02     2019-01-02
    6       CS002             mca02     2019-01-10
    7       CS009T              mca02   2019-01-16
    8       CS014               mca02   2019-01-29
    9       CS014               mca02   2019-01-29
    10      CS008               mca05   2019-01-14
    11      CS003P              mca03   2019-01-15
    12      CS015P              mca03   2019-01-15
    13      CS009T              mca02   2019-01-15
```

The teacher attendance table assigns a `unique numeric id` to every class.

The student attendance table records the student ids of students present in that class.

I want to display the following in a single query for a specific input `student_id`:

```
subject_code, subject_title, classes_attended, total_classes, % attendance
```

With this query :

```
SELECT subject_code, subject_title, count(class_no) as attended 
FROM 
  student_attendance 
  INNER JOIN teacher_attendance USING (class_no) 
  INNER JOIN subjects USING (subject_code) 
WHERE 
  student_id='mca1701' 
GROUP BY 
  subject_code
```

I am able to get `subject_code, subject_title, classes_attended` :

Sample op:

```
subject_code    subject_title             attended  
CS009P          Subject 9 prac                  2
CS009T          Subject 9 theory                1
```

And from this query I can get total_classes :

```
select subject_code,subject_title,count(class_no) as total_classes 
from teacher_attendance 
     INNER JOIN subjects USING (subject_code) 
WHERE semester= (SELECT semester from students where student_id='mca1701') 
GROUP BY subject_code
```

Sample op:

```
subject_code    subject_title          total_classes    
CS008              Subject8             1
CS009P             Subject9 Practical   2
CS009T              Subject9 Theory     2
```

I want to get the following data in a single query:

Required output :

```
subject_code    subject_title          attended         total      %att
    CS009P        Subject 9 prac            2             2        100%
    CS009T        Subject 9 theory          1             2         50%
    CS007         Subject7                  0             0          0
    CS008         Subject8                  0             1          0
```

UPDATE:

Got the answer thanks to  Joakim Danielson. Only changed the second JOIN TO LEFT JOIN in his answer which shows the empty rows as null which is good enough.

Solution:

```
SELECT u.subject_code, u.subject_title,t_count,s_count
FROM subjects u 
    JOIN students ON students.semester=u.semester 
       AND students.student_id='mca1701'
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT subject_code, COUNT(*) t_count 
       FROM teacher_attendance GROUP BY subject_code) tc
       ON tc.subject_code = u.subject_code
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) s_count,subject_code 
       FROM student_attendance INNER JOIN teacher_attendance 
       USING (class_no) WHERE student_id='mca1701' 
       GROUP BY subject_code) sc 
       ON sc.subject_code = u.subject_code
GROUP BY u.subject_code, u.subject_title
```

If anyone can simplify this query I will be thankful.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (All as formatted text, not images.)

Comment: @jarlh I have added some sample data.

Comment: Don't forget the "_I want to fetch the total `classes attended' as well as 'total classes taken' of each subject for the student in 1 query._" part.

Comment: create two objects for student_attendance and teacher_attendance and modify the query according in group by. something like count(student_attendance.class_no) as attended,count(teacher_attendance.class_no) as total_class_taken.

Comment: @ManjunathRao It does not work. total_class_taken is giving the wrong value. I think it is because I am doing an inner join using class_no.

Comment: Add some sample data for students and subjects

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have added some more data that may be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

New version to include all subjects attended by a teacher

```
SELECT u.subject_code, u.subject_title, count(s.class_no) as attended , tc.t_count total,  CONCAT(FORMAT(100 * count(s.class_no) / tc.t_count, 0), '%') '%att'
FROM subjects u
LEFT JOIN teacher_attendance t ON t.subject_code = u.subject_code
JOIN (SELECT subject_code, COUNT(*) t_count FROM teacher_attendance GROUP BY subject_code) tc ON tc.subject_code = u.subject_code
LEFT JOIN student_attendance s ON t.class_no = s.class_no AND s.student_id = 'mca1701'
WHERE semester = 3
GROUP BY u.subject_code,  u.subject_title
```

---

I used a separate sub query to count total value. (I skipped the subjects table but it's easy to add)

```
SELECT t.subject_code, count(t.class_no) as attended , tc.t_count total,   CONCAT(FORMAT(100 * count(t.class_no) / tc.t_count, 0), '%') %att
FROM student_attendance s
JOIN teacher_attendance t ON t.class_no = s.class_no
JOIN (SELECT subject_code, COUNT(*) t_count FROM teacher_attendance GROUP BY subject_code) tc ON tc.subject_code = t.subject_code
WHERE student_id='mca1701' 
GROUP BY subject_code
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It somewhat worked. But for the subjects that the student has not attended any classes the attendance  is not showing.

Comment: @NishantAgarwal, yes this is because I didn't include the subjects table

Comment: But for the subject where total classes is 1 and classes attended is 0, the row is not present. Can help me join the subjects table and show the remaining rows?

Comment: @NishantAgarwal new version with also S008 included in result, S007 I don't really understand how it can be accessed.

Comment: We have a semester field in students table which is semester 3 for mca1701. We need to show all the subject code from the subjects table where the semester is 3 in the attendance sheet of mca1701

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186848/discussion-between-nishant-agarwal-and-joakim-danielson).